# Auto-resize background-image to fit smaller windows and mobile devices - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, mobile

Although there are many answers to this question, I cannot find one that fits my needs. When I use my site on mobile, or even make my browser window on my laptop very small, I lose the full image that i'm using as a background-image.

HTML:

```
<div class="compete">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Compete</h2>
        <p>Winners always win</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.compete{
  background-image:url('Handlebars.jpg');
  height:450px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ff6a00;
}
.compete .container {
  position:relative;
  top:40px;
}
```

Any ideas on how to keep using my backgrond-image and yet have it auto-resize so I can see the full image on a mobile/small window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting background-size:100% 100%

CSS

```
.compete{
  background-image:url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff');
height:450px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
border-bottom:1px solid #ff6a00;
}
.compete .container {
position:relative;
top:40px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="compete">
<div class="container">
    <h2>Compete</h2>
    <p>Winners always win</p>
</div>
```

Do come back if you still face any issue.

Comment: Sort of works. But the 100% 100% distorts the image upon changing the size of the window. I actually can't see me getting exactly what I want - your solution is rather close nonetheless.

Comment: then use media screen and set the size for .compete class. This will be helpful for not distorting images on different viewports.

Comment: Expand? Think you're definitely on to something - not sure exactly what you mean by "use media screen"?

Comment: If you are trying to open on small device like mobile then surely you won't like it to cover 450px of the mobile. And for tabs and other devices b/w mobile and desktop you may like to set it less than 450px. 
Check out this fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/t9htjmx1/

Comment: Love the mobile tips - really appreciate that. I'm new to the HTML/CSS/JS game so all the tips like this are really valuable to me. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88321/discussion-between-coderomeos-and-jmn8).